# EF: Many tables with the same column - can I access to it without copying the code?

Tags: entity-framework

I have some tables which stores the file's data, e.g `TabA`, `TabB`, `TabC`, ... `TabX`. Each of them has the same column `FileTypeID`.

For each table I need to use the extension method to get the rows depending of the condition of the `FileTypeID` column. To do so, I have an extension method like that:

```
public static class FilesTab_Extenders
{
    public static IList<TabA> GetSpecificFiles(this EntityCollection<TabA> mc)
    {
        ///
    }
}
```

but, I don't want mindlessly clone the same code for the rest of tables. The only difference will be the parameter - `this EntityCollection<TabB>`, `this EntityCollection<TabC>` etc. So, is it somehow possible to make the universal code for that scenario ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the easiest way to do this would be to use an interface.  You would then have your partial classes implement this interface and use it in your extention method:

```
public interface IFileTypeable
{
    Guid FileTypeId { get; set;}
}
```

Now you would create partial class files for each of your TabA, TabB, TabC, ... TabX that follow this template:

```
namespace MyDBContextNamespace
{
    public partial class TabA : IFileTypeable
    {
        // no need to do anything, the property is already implemented on the original class file.
    }

    public partial class TabB : IFileTypeable
    {
        // no need to do anything, the property is already implemented on the original class file.
    }
}
```

Finally your extention method would be changed to look like this:

```
public static IList<IFileTypeable> GetSpecificFiles(this EntityCollection<IFileTypeable> mc)             
{             
    foreach (var item in mc)
    {
        Guid fileTypeId = item.FileTypeId;       
    }
}
```